# Regular Expression for URL that matches home/index page

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that will indicate if the URL provided is the index page of the site. This means it has to match `example.com`, `example.com/` and `example.com/index.php` but not `example.com/page.php`

Here's a list that I came up with for testing. So many permutations due to www/non-www, http/https, trailing slashes, etc.

It should match these:

- `http://example.com/index.php`
- `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com`
- `http://example.com/index.php?var=X`
- `http://example.com/?var=X`
- `http://example.com?var=X`
- `https://example.com/index.php`
- `https://example.com/`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://example.com/index.php?var=X`
- `https://example.com/?var=X`
- `https://example.com?var=X`
- `http://www.example.com/index.php`
- `http://www.example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com/index.php?var=X`
- `http://www.example.com/?var=X`
- `http://www.example.com?var=X`
- `https://www.example.com/index.php`
- `https://www.example.com/`
- `https://www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com/index.php?var=X`
- `https://www.example.com/?var=X`
- `https://www.example.com?var=X`

It should NOT match these

- `http://example.com/page.php`
- `http://example.com/page.php?var=X`
- `http://example.com/page`
- `http://example.com/page/`
- `http://example.com/page/index.php`
- `http://example.com/page?var=X`
- `http://example.com/page/?var=X`
- `https://example.com/page.php`
- `https://example.com/page.php?var=X`
- `https://example.com/page`
- `https://example.com/page/`
- `https://example.com/page/index.php`
- `https://example.com/page?var=X`
- `https://example.com/page/?var=X`
- `http://www.example.com/page.php`
- `http://www.example.com/page.php?var=X`
- `http://www.example.com/page`
- `http://www.example.com/page/`
- `http://www.example.com/page/index.php`
- `http://www.example.com/page?var=X`
- `http://www.example.com/page/?var=X`
- `https://www.example.com/page.php`
- `https://www.example.com/page.php?var=X`
- `https://www.example.com/page`
- `https://www.example.com/page/`
- `https://www.example.com/page/index.php`
- `https://www.example.com/page?var=X`
- `https://www.example.com/page/?var=X`

(Are there any other combinations I left out?)

All I've come up with so far is:

`example.com(/|index.php|)`

which is obviously incorrect as it is matching the `/page` values too.

Comment: For what language? Pure regex might not be the best approach here.

Comment: A regex is almost certainly *not* the way to go here.  Parsing the URL with a URL parser and then analyzing the path returned from it is the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This **works**

```
^https?://[^/]+(/(\?.*|index\.php(\?.*)?)?)?$
```

Note this is a generic regex. To match your flavor you might need to escape.

After running a simple test with `egrep` here is the result

```
$ while read x 
>       do 
>           if  echo $x | egrep '^https?://[^/]+(/(\?.*|index\.php(\?.*)?)?)?$' > /dev/null
>           then  
>               echo MATCH $x
>           else 
>               echo NOT MATCH $x 
>           fi
>       done < data
MATCH http://example.com/index.php
MATCH http://example.com/
MATCH http://example.com
MATCH http://example.com/index.php?var=X
MATCH http://example.com/?var=X
MATCH http://example.com?var=X
MATCH https://example.com/index.php
MATCH https://example.com/
MATCH https://example.com
MATCH https://example.com/index.php?var=X
MATCH https://example.com/?var=X
MATCH https://example.com?var=X
MATCH http://www.example.com/index.php
MATCH http://www.example.com/
MATCH http://www.example.com
MATCH http://www.example.com/index.php?var=X
MATCH http://www.example.com/?var=X
MATCH http://www.example.com?var=X
MATCH https://www.example.com/index.php
MATCH https://www.example.com/
MATCH https://www.example.com
MATCH https://www.example.com/index.php?var=X
MATCH https://www.example.com/?var=X
MATCH https://www.example.com?var=X
NOT MATCH http://example.com/page.php
NOT MATCH http://example.com/page.php?var=X
NOT MATCH http://example.com/page
NOT MATCH http://example.com/page/
NOT MATCH http://example.com/page/index.php
NOT MATCH http://example.com/page?var=X
NOT MATCH http://example.com/page/?var=X
NOT MATCH https://example.com/page.php
NOT MATCH https://example.com/page.php?var=X
NOT MATCH https://example.com/page
NOT MATCH https://example.com/page/
NOT MATCH https://example.com/page/index.php
NOT MATCH https://example.com/page?var=X
NOT MATCH https://example.com/page/?var=X
NOT MATCH http://www.example.com/page.php
NOT MATCH http://www.example.com/page.php?var=X
NOT MATCH http://www.example.com/page
NOT MATCH http://www.example.com/page/
NOT MATCH http://www.example.com/page/index.php
NOT MATCH http://www.example.com/page?var=X
NOT MATCH http://www.example.com/page/?var=X
NOT MATCH https://www.example.com/page.php
NOT MATCH https://www.example.com/page.php?var=X
NOT MATCH https://www.example.com/page
NOT MATCH https://www.example.com/page/
NOT MATCH https://www.example.com/page/index.php
NOT MATCH https://www.example.com/page?var=X
NOT MATCH https://www.example.com/page/?var=X
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Now I just have to get my brain to understand all those question marks. As a side note, when I test using http://regexpal.com/, anything that doesn't resemble a url also matches (ie 'asdasdasd'). It should be fine since I'll only be testing URLs, just thought it was weird.

Comment: As I told you you need to escape properly. Its POSIX regex. convert to your favorite flavor accordingly or find the POSIX supported functions in your language.

Comment: @ShaneN just check its works on regexpal.com too. See [this](http://url.ie/go8i).

Comment: You can use the following to capture also URLs with an anchor at the end (e.g. http://example.com/#test or http://example.com#test):

^https?:\/\/[^/]+(\/(\?.*|#.*|index\.php(\?.*)?)?)?$

Answer (score 0):

Say you're doing this in PHP.  You should use `parse_url()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then look at the path element.

```
<?php
$url = "http://example.com/index.php?page=1";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
print "path=$path\n";
?>
```

Run that and you get

```
path=/index.php
```

Once you have just the path in `$path`, it's just a matter of matching to `/` or `/index.php` or whatever.  No regexes necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I was able to use PHP. But instead I'm using this within a tool that only allows regexps.

Comment: So what is the tool?  Maybe we can help work around the regex-only restriction.

Comment: Hey Andy - It's for Google Tag Manager. I need to define a rule for when someone is on the index page. Only way I saw that being possible is if we set a rule that fires when url matches regex. Other options are just if url contains, starts with, ends with, etc. It seems like a cool tool but I'm just now experimenting with it. Have you used it before?

Comment: I haven't, and I looked at the docs briefly, and it's surprising to me that they only give you the entire URL, not individual elements like path or query string.  Maybe another solution might be to put an element on your home page that signifies "I am a home page" and use the DOM-based rules to detect it.

Comment: Hey Andy - I agree - path or query string would be helpful - perhaps they're working on it as this is still pretty new. And using the dom-based rules to find a specific home page element might be a better approach overall, as this regexp seems overkill. Thanks for the insight!